# XML DeSerializer: returns first word from a tag whose value is string with spaces in C#

Tags: c#, xml, split, return

My Xml file has following values:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<CASAuthXML xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<Username>username</Username>
<Password>password</Password>
<ExpectedTitlePage>xml values with spaces</ExpectedTitlePage>
</CASAuthXML>
```

Below program retrieves the XML values from a xml file.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
namespace Framework.Utils
{
    public class CASAuthXML
    {
        public string Username;
        public string Password;
        public string ExpectedTitlePage;
        public string GetCASCredentials()
        {
            CASAuthXML values = new CASAuthXML();
            XmlSerializer reader = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CASAuthXML));
            StreamReader file = new StreamReader(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "//XMLFile.xml");
            values = (CASAuthXML)reader.Deserialize(file);
            file.Close();
            Username = values.Username;
            Password = values.Password;
            ExpectedTitlePage = values.ExpectedTitlePage;
            return Username + " " + Password + " " + ExpectedTitlePage;

        }

    }
```

}

Here the method returns exact title page retrieved from the XML file. **But the problem is** as the method returns strings spliting from the XML, the value of ExpectedTitlePage in code below is only **xml**, While I expect all **xml values with spaces** as value of ExpectedTitlePage.

```
public static void Authenticate(IWebDriver driver, string ExpectedTitlePage, string username, string password)`
{
string actualPageTitle = driver.Title;


        if (actualPageTitle != ExpectedTitlePage)
        {
            FatalError.OnError("Error authenticating. Web driver is currently at page: " + actualPageTitle, "CASError");
         }
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("username")).SendKeys(username);
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("password")).SendKeys(password);
        driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input.btnNormal")).Click();


}
```

How to return all strings to the authenticate class?

Comment: I tested your code with a local xml file, and it works as expected...

Comment: This has nothing to do with the XML serializer. Your code returns everything as one string, separated with spaces. When this string is then split again (on spaces), obviously it will fail if the final string contains spaces. Find the part in the code that issues `String.Split` and use the overload that accepts a maximum number of parts (in this case, 3).

Comment: @PhilipW Yes we get all the value 'xml values with spaces' in variable ExpectedTitlePage but only the first string is returned in public static void Authenticate(IWebDriver driver, string ExpectedTitlePage, string username, string password)`
Can you make sure if you get all the value or only the first one in Authenticate( string ExpectedTitlePage)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use **Xmlreader**, this would allow you to get your xml elements with White-spaces, here a nice answer that show you how to implement it: [XmlReader StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33153547/6677003)

Comment: Why would you do this when `XmlSerializer` does all the work for you?